# How to get plain text of a MS Office file using COM API (office automation) in c++

Tags: c++, api, text, com, office-automation

I have a buffer that contains part a Office word document. I want to use COM API to fetch plain text of the buffer. I know how to open a word document and save it a text document using COM API, but it is not what I want.
As a solution I create a memory-mapped file object and put my data to it and then I tried to open it using COM API, But "Invoke" says "Bad variable type".

```
hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(
    INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,    // use paging file
    NULL,                    // default security
    PAGE_READWRITE,          // read/write access
    0,                       // maximum object size (high-order DWORD)
    BUF_SIZE,                // maximum object size (low-order DWORD)
    szName);                 // name of mapping object

///....
// copy data to hMapFile
///....

////... 
// create an instance of Word Application
///...


/// now call open function and send hMapFile instead of a real file

VARIANTARG varg;
varg.vt = VT_BYREF;
//varg.vt = BSTR;
//varg.bstrVal = BSTR(L"F:\\sample2.docx"); 
varg.byref = hMapFile; 

DISPPARAMS dpOpen = { &varg, NULL, 1, 0 };

DISPID dispOpenID;
LPOLESTR szOpenDoc = L"Open";
UINT err = 9;

hr = m_pDocuments->GetIDsOfNames(IID_NULL, &szOpenDoc, 1, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, &dispOpenID);

hr = m_pDocuments->Invoke(dispOpenID, IID_NULL, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_METHOD, &dpOpen, &varRetVal, &excepInfo, &err);
```

Comment: What makes you think the `Documents` object should accept anything else than a file name or path?